# background image using css not working when using image source to base64 on mozilla

Tags: css, image, base64, mozilla

I have a style class defined as this :

```
 .img-info32, .img-confirm32 ,.img-error32, .img-warning32{
    background: url('images/info32.png') no-repeat center center;
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
}
```

then i have an image with the source a base64 image like this :

```
     <img src="data:image/png;base64,........." class="infoLarge img-confirm32" alt="Informations">
```

when testing using chrome the background image is well applied, whereas in mozilla the base64 image is showing up instead of the background specified using the css class. Why this ? And where am i getting it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. My base64 image is a png file, when changing it to a gif, then my background is applied correctly. I don't know why gif and png is making a difference, but it is the case.